# Gale Shapley matching algorithm with Polygamy by Men Upto four Marriages Using Bipartite Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite, matchmaking

How to modify Gale Shapley matching algorithm with Polygamy by Men Upto four Marriages Using Bipartite Graph

I want to add weights to each node of bipartite graph based on certain criteria for example age, height , education etc after all the nodes are assigned weight algorithm will be executed that recommend best possible stable matches as per the priorities of the men and women.

Conditions:

1. One man can marry one women, One man can marry two women, one man can marry three women but not more than four women at a time
2. In case of divorce or death of any women a men can get one more.
3. If man dies all females could get marry again after three months.
4. One women could marry one man at a time.
5. In case of divorce female can remarry after three months.

## Import Python Libraries

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Example preference lists for 3 men and 3 women

```
men_prefs = {
    'm1': ['w2', 'w1', 'w3'],
    'm2': ['w1', 'w2', 'w3'],
    'm3': ['w1', 'w3', 'w2']
}
women_prefs = {
    'w1': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2'],
    'w2': ['m2', 'm1', 'm3'],
    'w3': ['m1', 'm3', 'm2']
}
```

## Create the bipartite graph

```
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(men_prefs.keys(), bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(women_prefs.keys(), bipartite=1)
for man, prefs in men_prefs.items():
    for woman in prefs:
        B.add_edge(man, woman)
```

## Run the Gale-Shapley algorithm

```
free_men = set(men_prefs.keys())
engaged = {}
while free_men:
    man = free_men.pop()
    woman = men_prefs[man][0]
    if woman in engaged:
        current_man = engaged[woman]
        if women_prefs[woman].index(man) < women_prefs[woman].index(current_man):
            engaged[woman] = man
            free_men.add(current_man)
        else:
            free_men.add(man)
    else:
        engaged[woman] = man
```

## Draw the graph with the new matching

```
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(B, men_prefs.keys())
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(B, pos, node_color=['lightblue'])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(B, pos, edgelist=engaged.items(), edge_color='red', width=2)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(B, pos, font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: *"I need your help to resolve it"*: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

Make a number of copies of each man.  Run the usual algorithm.  Recombine men to get your answer.

More general variations can be solved by writing it as a max flow problem and then using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm.

Comment: In case of making copies of men, output of the algorithm will be invalid with respect of female matching choices. Any other possible solution ?